# IOUtils.closeQuitely for FileChannel

Tags: java, io, filechannel

I wanted to know the Apache library method IOUtils.closeQuitely does well with FileChannel.
I see it takes Closeable as argument and FileChannel does implement it up in hierarachy. But
can we face any issue down the line. Any experience one can share please.

Comment: Pls check this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268465/disposing-streams-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's OK if we use it as IOUtils.closeQuietly API suggests, ie double-close

```
    FileChannel ch = null;
    try {
        ch = new FileInputStream("foo.txt").getChannel();
        // process
        ch.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // error handling
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }
```

But try-with-resources if Java 7 is available is a much cleaner way.