# "using" keyword in java

Tags: c#, java, using

In Java is there an equivalent to the [C# "using" statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx) allowing to define a scope for an object:

```
using (AwesomeClass hooray = new AwesomeClass())
{
   // Great code
}
```