# Close resource quietly using try-with-resources

Tags: java, exception, java-7, try-with-resources

Is it possible to ignore the exception thrown when a resource is closed using a try-with-resources statement?

Example:

```
class MyResource implements AutoCloseable{
  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Could not close");
  }  
  public void read() throws Exception{      
  }
}

//this method prints an exception "Could not close"
//I want to ignore it
public static void test(){
  try(MyResource r = new MyResource()){
    r.read();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Or should I continue to close in a `finally` instead?

```
public static void test2(){
  MyResource r = null;
  try {
     r.read();
  }
  finally{
    if(r!=null){
      try {
        r.close();
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found this answered on the coin-dev mailing list:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-April/001503.html

> **5. Some failures of the close method can be safely ignored (e.g.,
>   closing a file that was open for read). Does the construct provide for
>   this?**
>
> No. While this functionality seems attractive, it is not clear that
>   it's worth the added complexity. As a practical matter these “harmless
>   exceptions” rarely if ever occur, so a program will be no more robust
>   if these exceptions are ignored. If you feel you must ignore them,
>   there is a workaround, but it isn't pretty:

```
static void copy(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    boolean done = false;
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
        try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int n;
            while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        done = true;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        if (!done)
            throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: it isn't pretty. any other idea by now?

Answer (score 25):

You could use a decorator pattern here to close the resource quietly:

```
public class QuietResource<T extends AutoCloseable> implements AutoCloseable{
    T resource;
    public QuietResource(T resource){
        this.resource = resource;
    }
    public T get(){
        return resource;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            resource.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            // suppress exception
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm not personally a fan of the resulting syntax, but maybe this works for you:

```
public static void test(){
    try(QuietResource<MyResource> qr = new QuietResource<>(new MyResource())){
        MyResource r = qr.get();
        r.read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

You can do better if you're willing to limit yourself to dealing with interfaces and leverage a Dynamic Proxy Class:

```
public class QuietResource<T> implements InvocationHandler {

    private T resource;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <V extends AutoCloseable> V asQuiet(V resource){
        return (V) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                resource.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                resource.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                new QuietResource<V>(resource));
    }

    public QuietResource(T resource){
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if(m.getName().equals("close")){
            try {
                return m.invoke(resource, args);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Suppressed exception with message: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
                // suppress exception
                return null;
            }
        }
        return m.invoke(resource, args);
    }
}
```

Then assuming you have:

```
public interface MyReader extends AutoCloseable{
    int read();
}
```

With an actual resource class:

```
public class MyResource implements MyReader {

    public void close() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("ha!");
    }

    public int read(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Calling syntax would look like:

```
public static void test(){
    try(MyReader r = QuietResource.asQuiet(new MyResource())){
        r.read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

You can do better than this if you want to start including libraries, like AOP enablers. These solutions, however, will work out of the box with JDK7 and no other dependencies.

Comment: You should remove `throws Exception` from `close()` to document the catched exception and simplify usage.

Comment: @Mark Elliot You _can_ implement interface method declared with throws with class method not declared any throws.

Answer (score 6):

This is one solution:

```
    boolean ok=false;
    try(MyResource r = new MyResource())
    {
        r.read();
        ok=true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if(ok)
            ; // ignore
        else
            // e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
    }
```

If `ok==true` and we got an exception, it definitely comes from `close()`.

If `ok==false`, `e` comes from `read()` or constructor. `close()` will still be called and may throw `e2`, but e2 will be suppressed anyway.

The code is quite readable without going through such analysis. Intuitively it says, if `ok==true`, our real work is done, and we don't really care what errors come after that regarding the resource.

Answer (score -1):

I don't actually recommend this but the only way I can imagine to do this is examining the Exception's stacktrace.  Did it come from within a nearby close method?

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753924/32453 any caught exception will either be an "exception" from the main block, an exception from the close calls, or an exception from the try block with "suppressed" close calls.

So you just have to figure out if it's an exception from the close call itself, which is the line of the `catch`, apparently:

```
try (Resource myResource = new Resource()) {

} catch (IOException mightBeFromClose) {
  int currentLine = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
  int lineOfCatch = currentLine - 1;
  String currentFilename = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName();
  boolean exceptionWasFromClose = Stream.of(mightBeFromClose.getStackTrace()).anyMatch(l -> l.getFileName().equals(currentFilename) && l.getLineNumber() == lineOfCatch);
  if (exceptionWasFromClose) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

A few more things to consider:

In general it is not clear if you'd want to handle `IOException` from a `close` call different than one from inside the try block.  What if a close call implies it didn't flush all data out to the file?  You may want to handle/treat them all the same.

Another option: close the resource manually near the end of the block (with its own try-catch).  Double-close is typically allowed so you could catch the close Exception there.

Another possibility: use normal try-catch-finally pattern instead, here are some ways to make it slightly less ugly: [Java try-finally inside try-catch pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7433228/32453) might be an option if you don't have multiple resources.