# Exception coming out of close() in try-with-resource

Tags: java, java-7, try-with-resources

I was reading about the try-with-resource in JDK7 and while I was thinking of upgrading my application to run with JDK7 I faced this problem..

When using a BufferedReader for example the write throws IOException and the close throws IOException.. in the catch block I am concerned in the IOException thrown by the write.. but I wouldn't care much about the one thrown by the close..

Same problem with database connections.. and any other resource..

As an example I've created an auto closeable resource:

```
public class AutoCloseableExample implements AutoCloseable {

    public AutoCloseableExample() throws IOException{
        throw new IOException();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("An Exception During Close");
    }

}
```

Now when using it:

```
public class AutoCloseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (AutoCloseableExample example = new AutoCloseableExample()) {
            System.out.println(example);

            throw new IOException("An Exception During Read");
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println(x.getMessage());
        } 
    }

}
```

how can I distinguish between such exceptions without having to create wrappers for classes such as BufferedReader?

Most of cases I put the resource close in a try/catch inside the finally block without caring much about handling it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets consider the class:

```
public class Resource implements AutoCloseable {

    public Resource() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Exception from constructor");
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Exception from method");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Exception from closeable");
    }
}
```

and the try-with-resource block:

```
    try(Resource r = new Resource()) {
        r.doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**1.** All 3 throw statements enabled.

Message "Exception from constructor" will printed and the exception thrown by constructor will be **suppressed**, that means you can't catch it.

**2.** The throw in constructor is removed.

Now the stack trace will print "Exception from method" and "Suppressed: Exception from closeable" below. Here you also can't catch the suppressed exception thrown by close method, but you will be nofitied about the suppressed exception.

**3.** Throws from constructor and method are removed.

As you have probably already guessed the "Exception from closeable" will be printed.

**Important tip:** In all of above situations you are actually **catching all exceptions**, no matter where they were throwed. So if you use try-with-resource block you don't need to wrap the block with another try-catch, the extra block is simply useless.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.. I totally understand this.. the problem I am thinking of is how to distinguish between exceptions thrown from methods like doSomething() and the close() method since both throw the same type of exception.. the doSomething() deserves a catch as something in the flow occurs.. while the exception thrown from the close() isn't that much of importance in most cases and gets me confused..

Comment: Ok, now I see what's your point. If you want to distinguish exceptions from the code you could get the exception's method name by `ex.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()`. If not you could just print the stack trace and read it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a flag as in the following example:

```
static String getData() throws IOException {
    boolean isTryCompleted = false;
    String theData = null;
    try (MyResource br = new MyResource();) {

        theData = br.getData();
        isTryCompleted = true;

    } catch(IOException e) {
        if (!isTryCompleted )
            throw e;
        // else it's a close exception and it can be ignored
    }

    return theData;
}
```

> source:[Close resource quietly using try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889697/close-resource-quietly-using-try-with-resources)