# unlocking a lock.tryLock with timeout

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have this code

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

void someMethod() {
    try {
        if (lock.tryLock(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // timed out 
            throw new RuntimeException("timeout");
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This works fine except when when it times out. Since the thread that timesout does not own the lock, `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown. There is no `isHeldByCurrentThread` in `Lock` interface. If I dont want to cast to `ReentrantLock`, I have to use something ugly

```
...
} finally {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        lock.unlock();
        lock.unlock(); // twice because tryLock is called twice
    }
}
```

or

```
...
} finally {
    if ( !timeout ) {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Any better options ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only unlock if you acquired the lock:

```
if (lock.tryLock(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
  try {
    // Do stuff.
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Note that:

- [There is an example like this in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock());
- This idiom doesn't have anything to do with using the timeout: you would not want to unlock the lock of a call to `lock()` were interrupted. You should always acquire the lock outside, but immediately before, the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)  is another option ( in addition to Andy's answer ) but `Lock` is not `AutoCloseable` .

So you can write a wrappper as explained [here in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965731/are-locks-autocloseable)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435639/why-not-using-a-try-with-lock-in-java)  then you can use try-with-resource with this wrapper.

Probably, its not worth the effort if you are not planning to use similar construct at multiple places in your application.

**EDIT :** Elaborating answer to address Sotirios Delimanolis's concerns .

In my opinion , OP wants to throw a `RuntimeException` if lock can't be acquired and is confused about closing of lock in `finally` block since it might throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` if lock is not already held by thread.

Using `Lock` gives you flexibility to `unlock` at any place that programmer wants ( and not necessarily at the end of try block or at the end of method ) & that flexibility is missing in `synchronized` keyword but as per code snippet of OP, it seems he will unlock just after finishing immediate `try` block so `AutoCloseable` makes sense.

Below code addresses both concerns ,

**Wrapper class**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class CloseableReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock implements
        AutoCloseable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public CloseableReentrantLock timedLock() throws InterruptedException{
        if(this.tryLock(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            return this;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("timeout");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.unlock();

    }

}
```

**Client**

`try(CloseableReentrantLock lock = new CloseableReentrantLock().timedLock())
{
  //do stuff here

}`

**Lock Acquired Scenario** : Nothing special happens , `close` method is called after try-with-resource block and lock is unlocked. This is more or less the way `synchronized` block works but you can't get a waiting time option with `synchronized` but the `finally` code cluttering & chances that programmer will miss to code `unlock` & `finally` are not there with `syncronized` and so is the case with `Closeable` wrapper.

**Lock can't be Acquired** : In this scenario, since resource is not successfully acquired with in try-with-resource and **try-with-resource** itself throws Exception, `close` will not be called on this resource and so `IllegalMonitorStateException` will not be there. 
Refer [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657737/exception-coming-out-of-close-in-try-with-resource) to understand more for exceptions from within **try-with-resource** itself.

This sample code illustrates it further,

```
public class TryResource implements AutoCloseable{


    public TryResource getResource(boolean isException) throws Exception{
        if ( isException) throw new Exception("Exception from closeable getResource method");
        else return this;
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In doSomething method");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In close method");
        throw new Exception("Exception from closeable close method");
    }

}
```

and client,

```
public class TryResourceClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (TryResource resource = new TryResource().getResource(true)){
            resource.doSomething();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is it an option if it's not `AutoCloseable`? Even with the wrapper, how would it deal with failure to lock? Why bring it up if it's not worth the effort?

Comment: I have updated answer to illustrate more about what I meant & what I understood about OP's requirements. On the worth the effort part, I am not sure if he is going to need that syntax one time or thousand times in his application so if you need it thousand times, its better not to clutter your code with finally blocks and let unlocking be done automatically at single place.

Comment: i have this construct in one place only so will stick with nested try block. but i agree this is much cleaner. thanks for taking time to elaborate