# How to catch exception thrown by close method in try-with-resource statement

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I was reading about `try-with-resource` statement in Java which can be used to specify any number of resources.

```
try (Resource1 res1 = initialize_code; Resource1 res2 = initialize_code; ...) 
{
    statement;
}
```

Now when the try block exits (normally or abnormally throwing an exception) the `close` methods of all resource objects are invoked. But some `close` methods can throw exceptions. What will happen in that scenario if `close` itself throws exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But some close methods can throw exceptions.

Yes they can and you are right. Also the resources are closed in reverse order of their initialization.

> What will happen if `close` method itself throws exception?

As you mentioned some `close` methods can also throw exceptions. If that happens when try block is executed normally then the exception is thrown to caller.

**But what when another exception had been thrown, causing `close`
methods of the resources to be called, and one of the `close` method throws an exception (exception of lower importance actually)?**

In this situation original exception gets rethrown and the exceptions caused by `close` method
are also caught and attached as [supressed exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849416/what-is-a-suppressed-exception). This is actually one of the advantge using try-with-resource becuase implementing such mechanism would be tedious to implement by hand.

```
try {
 ///statements.
} catch (IOException e) { 
   Throwable[] supressedExceptions = ex.getSupressed();
}
```