# Java equivalent of C# 'using' statement

Tags: c#, java, file, exception, using

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“using” keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943542/using-keyword-in-java)

I'm transitioning from C# to java, so please bear with me...

When reading a file in C#, you simply wrap it all in a big 'using' block, so that if you have an exception, the file will still be closed. Like so (maybe inaccurate but you get the idea):

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\myfile.txt")) {
  // Any exceptions while reading the file here won't leave the file open
}
```

Is there a convenient equivalent in java 5 or 6? I get the impression that lately java has been 'borrowing' some of the syntactic sugar from c# (such as foreach) and so i wouldn't be surprised if there's a java equivalent of using these days.

Or do i just have to use a try..finally block? 'Using' is just so much nicer i think...

Comment: If you claim that a question is duplicate, it would be helpful if you provide a link to the question it is supposed to duplicate. Just marking things as duplicate is not helpful at all and makes this site less useful.
 
This question is a good example of why you must provide a link: when I click on the tag "using", I get 568 hits -- next to impossible to find the original answer in such a long list. If I search for [using] [java] I still get 24 hits and the answer I am looking for is on the *second* page of the list of results:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943542/using-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no equivalent syntax sugar using statements in Java 5 or 6. However, a [proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000011.html) for automatic resource management which adds a familiar Disposable interface [seems to have been accepted](http://blogs.oracle.com/theplanetarium/entry/summarizing_java_language_changes_for) for Java 7 . Until then, you have to manually code a try...finally.

Answer (score 2):

Have to use **try .. finally**

P.S. foreach (iteration over a collection) is not an invention of C#

Comment: But `foreach` is just syntactic sugar, just like `using`, which is the OP's point.