# "using " keyword in c#, how to use in java?

Tags: c#, java, android, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“using” keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943542/using-keyword-in-java)

I have one problem, In `c#` "using " is keyword but how to use in `java`

```
using (layout xmds = new layout()){
}
```

Comment: what really you want to do ???

Comment: seems to be `java 7 try with resources`

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7, all classes implementing [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) can be used with the "[try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)" construct:

```
class Layout implements AutoCloseable { ... }

// Usage
try (Layout layout = new Layout()) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

**Edit:** Noticed you tagged the question with "android". Android doesn't support Java 7, so you won't be able to use try-with-resources there.