# Create a file from a ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, bytearrayoutputstream

Can someone explain how I can get a file object if I have only a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  How to create a file from a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can do it with using a `FileOutputStream` and the `writeTo` method.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = getByteStreamMethod();
try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("thefilename")) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
}
```

Source: ["Creating a file from ByteArrayOutputStream in Java." on Code Inventions](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/creating-file-from-bytearrayoutputstrea.html)

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen yeah ..obviously :)

Comment: Or use java 7 try with resources statement to completely get rid off finally block;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016299/does-java-have-a-using-statement

Comment: bro what if i dont have "thefilename" , insted i have byte[] stream of that excel, then what is the way?

Answer (score 35):

You can use a FileOutputStream for this.

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile")); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Put data in your baos

    baos.writeTo(fos);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    // Handle exception here
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work with `fos` in `try` block. Also, `new File()` is not required.

Comment: It's a good thing he added "new File()". It's easier for the reader to know there's a File constructor available.

Comment: This seems to be needed for Android.

Comment: Can be improved with fos inside try-with-resources () and dropping the finally